# Incorrect Fourier coefficients signs resulting from scipy.fft.fft

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing, fft

I analysed a triangle wave using the Fourier series by hand, and then using the `scipy.fft` package. What I'm getting are the same absolute values of the coefficients, but with opposite signs.
[image: Triangular wave]

**By hand:**
I took the interval [-1,1], calculated the integral to get **a0 = 1**, then **a1**, **a3** and **a5** using the result of integration:
[image: integral1]

And all the **bn** are 0.
Then I simply constructed the series, where the 1st term is **a0/2**, the second **a1×cos(n Pi t/T)** and so on, and plotted these waves, which summed give a good approximation of the original signal.
The coefficients are:

```
a0 = 0.5  
a1 = -0.4053  
a3 = -0.0450  
a5 = -0.0162
```

[image: individual waves] [image: summed waves]

**Scipy.fft:**
I defined the sampling frequency fs=50, and created the space for the function with `space=np.linspace(-1,1,2*fs)`.
Then defined the `fft1 = fft.fft(triang(space))`, where "triang" is the function which generates the signal. I immediately scaled the results by dividing by the number of samples (100) and multiplying each term except the 0th by 2. Next were the frequencies `freq1 = fft.fftfreq(space.shape[-1], d=1/fs)`.
The resulting coefficients (the real parts pertaining to **an**) are:

```
a0 = 0.5051  
a1 = 0.4091  
a3 = 0.0452  
a5 = 0.0161
```

As you can see, the absolute values are correct, but the signs are not. What am I missing?
[image: individual waves-scipy] [image: summed waves-scipy]

And one bonus question if I may - when doing it this way (using scipy) and plotting each wave separately, should I add the phase angle from `np.angle(fft1[n])` into each term, like **a1×cos(n Pi t/T + theta) + b1×sin(n Pi t/T + theta)**? I'd say yes, but in this example all the **bn** are 0, and so are the phase angles, so I couldn't really test it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that when you call `fft()`, you don’t pass in the time axis (`space`). So how is the function supposed to know you sampled from -1 to 1? It doesn’t! It assumes you sampled at 0, 1, 2, 3, … N-1.

This means that the FFT function sees the signal as shifted compared to your manual calculation, and a shift means the phase in the frequency domain changes.

If you sample your triangle function from 0 to 2, instead of -1 to 1, you should get a matching phase.

The difference between sampling with a frequency of 1, or any other frequency (ie samples not being at integer locations) is taken care of by `fftfreq()`, which just tells you the frequency that corresponds to each bin given your sampling frequency.