# How to determine the actual phase angles of component waves of a signal processed with scipy.fft?

Tags: python, scipy, fft

I used `scipy.fft` to transform a signal and find its components. The signal was randomly chosen, and the used code is shown below. When manually constructing the component waves, I am confused about the phase angle I need to add to each component.

```
tt = 10*np.pi
N = 1000
fs = N/tt
space = np.linspace(0,tt,N)
signal = lambda t: 2*np.sin(t) + np.cos(2*t)
```

The signal looks like this:
[image: original signal]

```
fft1 = fft.fft(signal(space))  
fft1t = fft1/len(space) # scaling the amplitudes
fft1t[1:] = fft1t[1:]*2 # scaling the amplitudes
freq = fft.fftfreq(space.shape[-1], d=1/fs)
```

The stemplot shows the correctly identified terms with their amplitudes, and the corresponding frequencies are identified from `freq` as 0.1592 for the 5th term and 0.3183 for the 10th term.

```
plt.stem(np.abs(fft1t)[:int(len(fft1t)/2)]) # plotting only up to the Nyquist freq.
plt.xlim(-.5,20)
plt.grid()
```

[image: stemplot]

Now when I plot try to manually reconstruct the signal, and plot is on top of the original, I get a phase mismatch by 2 times the phase angle calculated from the fft results.

```
uk = space**0 * fft1t[0].real
for n in [5,10]: # 5th and 10th term of the Fourier series
    uk += (fft1t[n].real * np.cos(n * np.pi * space / (N/fs/2) + 0*np.angle(fft1t[n])) 
         + fft1t[n].imag * np.sin(n * np.pi * space / (N/fs/2) + 0*np.angle(fft1t[n])))
sns.lineplot(x=space, y=signal(space))
sns.lineplot(x=space, y=uk)
```

[image: phase angle 0]

When I add one phase angle I get:

```
uk = space**0 * fft1t[0].real
for n in [5,10]: # 5th and 10th term of the Fourier series
        uk += (fft1t[n].real * np.cos(n * np.pi * space / (N/fs/2) + 1*np.angle(fft1t[n])) 
             + fft1t[n].imag * np.sin(n * np.pi * space / (N/fs/2) + 1*np.angle(fft1t[n])))
sns.lineplot(x=space, y=signal(space))
sns.lineplot(x=space, y=uk)
```

[image: phase angle 1]

And when I add two times the phase angle, then I get a perfect match:

```
uk = space**0 * fft1t[0].real
for n in [5,10]: # 5th and 10th term of the Fourier series
        uk += (fft1t[n].real * np.cos(n * np.pi * space / (N/fs/2) + 2*np.angle(fft1t[n])) 
             + fft1t[n].imag * np.sin(n * np.pi * space / (N/fs/2) + 2*np.angle(fft1t[n])))
sns.lineplot(x=space, y=signal(space))
sns.lineplot(x=space, y=uk)
```

[image: phase angle 2]

Please help me understand why am I required to double the calculated phase angle here, and what is the general rule for determining the phase angle to add. In another [question (example) I recently posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77150937/incorrect-fourier-coefficients-signs-resulting-from-scipy-fft-fft), I only had to add one times the phase angle. Is this connected to the sampling space, where instead of sampling from [-T,T] (like in the example from the link) we sample in [0,T] (like in this example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you compute for each frequency component is wrong.

If you want to use the phase, then you should also use the magnitude:

```
p = n * np.pi * space / (N/fs/2)
np.abs(fft1t[n]) * np.cos(p + np.angle(fft1t[n]))
```

That is, each frequency component represents a single shifted sine wave. A phase of 0 corresponds to an even function, hence we use the cosine, not the sine, to build that function.

If you want to use complex multiplication, then you don’t need to compute the phase separately, it is encoded in the complex numbers. The equation now is

```
fft1t[n] * (np.cos(p) + 1j * np.sin(p))
```

(which is equivalent to the multiplication with `exp(…)` in the other answer). But this form will produce both a real and imaginary component. The imaginary part would be cancelled when considering the corresponding negative frequency component. But you already discarded that component, and doubled the positive one, meaning the positive and negative components are already combined in some way. And thus we need to ignore the imaginary part that comes out:

```
fft1t[n] * (np.cos(p) + 1j * np.sin(p)).real
```

If we want to be a bit more efficient and never compute that imaginary component, then we need to properly expand this complex multiplication:

```
fft1t[n].real * np.cos(p) - fft1t[n].imag * np.sin(p)
```

(note the minus!)

Answer (score 1):

You will get more answers if you give complete code that people can run.

Note that numpy.linspace() as you are using it will generate a point at the end that you don't want.

You can reconstruct your signal just as a straightforward sum of complex exponentials (or simply use the library routine). You shouldn't be applying different scaling to each of the Fourier coefficients.

I don't see why you should need any phase angle.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import fft
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

tt = 10 * np.pi
N = 1000
fs = N / tt
space = np.linspace( 0, tt, N, endpoint=False )       # Note that last point isn't included
signal = lambda t: 2 * np.sin(t) + np.cos( 2 * t )
y = signal( space )

# Compute FFT
fft1 = fft.fft( y )

# Invert FFT by direct calculation!
uk = fft1[0]
for n in range( 1, N ):
   uk += fft1[n] * np.exp( (1.0j) * n * 2.0 * np.pi * space / tt )
uk = uk.real / N

x = space
plt.plot( x, y )
plt.plot( x, uk, 'x' )
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: How would you transform the complex exponentials into sine and cosine functions? Because that would probably help solving my confusion. Also, what's the deal with the point at the end of np.linspace?

Comment: For the complex exponentials: exp(ix)=cos(x)+i.sin(x). For the linspace call, your (implicit) assumption of periodicity means that y(0)=y(L), where L is the period. The last point is NOT included in the discrete Fourier transform; however, the default behaviour of linspace() is to include it, so you need the endpoint= parameter to stop that.

Comment: I understand Euler's formula, but could you try writing the above signal in terms of sines and cosines, as I tried in my example? Why is there no phase angle in your solution, and in my solution it looks like there should be one?

Comment: If you wish to use sines and cosines then you will also have to take into account that the Fourier coefficients are complex (in general) and so will have real and imaginary parts. Note that (a+bi)(c+di) has a real part of ac-bd: there's a MINUS sign there. There is no point in splitting it into sines and cosines in this instance; it is much simpler left as complex exponentials. I can assure you that no phase angle should be necessary. (I'm not sure why you contemplated including one.)

Comment: I'm not really getting what you're trying to say. Could you perhaps point the mistake I made in my code when trying to split into sines and cosines?

Comment: @Sjotroll, there are so many issues with your code that it is difficult to say which one caused your issues. You also didn't ever present complete runnable code, so some bits had to be guessed at. Amongst other things (1) the linspace call should have endPoint=false (although the effect is probably small for large N); (2) you appear to only use 3 Fourier coefficients (0,5,10); (3) You have applied different scaling factors to fft1[0] and fft1[the rest]; (4) you have incorrectly found the real part of a complex product (you need a minus sign before fft1t[n].imag[]) etc. etc.

Comment: @Sjotroll, I’ve been looking at your other thread. I think you are trying to use a discrete Fourier transform to create an analytical Fourier series in sines and cosines. Whilst there is some similarity, they really aren’t the same thing: the discrete Fourier transform is always a finite sum, rather than infinite series, and is more naturally framed (and certainly worked out) in terms of complex exponentials (albeit those could be expanded in sines and cosines). It’s most useful for digital signals.